# Spyder 3.2.8 cannot be launched in Anaconda 2 with environment of Python 3.6

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I just create an environment for `python 3.6` in `anaconda 2`, and then install spyder:

`conda install spyder`

in the newly created environment (called `python3`).

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    spyder: 3.2.8-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: \ DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(185): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\YL\Anaconda2\envs\python3', env_name: 'python3', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(299): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\FruitLab\Anaconda2\pythonw.exe, args are [u'C:\\YL\\Anaconda2\\cwp.py', u'C:\\YL\\Anaconda2\\envs\\python3', u'C:\\YL\\Anaconda2\\envs\\python3\\pythonw.exe', u'C:\\YL\\Anaconda2\\envs\\python3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py']
| DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(299): Shortcut cmd is C:\YL\Anaconda2\python.exe, args are [u'C:\\Users\\FruitLab\\Anaconda2\\cwp.py', u'C:\\YL\\Anaconda2\\envs\\python3', u'C:\\YL\\Anaconda2\\envs\\python3\\python.exe', u'C:\\YL\\Anaconda2\\envs\\python3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py', u'--reset']
done
```

Thereafter I also installed some other common packages (such as `numpy`, `scikit-learn`, `OpenCV`, et al.) in this environment. But the `Spyder (python 3)` cannot be launched for some reasons. The original `spyder` under the base environment of python2.7 still works normally.

Did I miss something in installing the `spyder` for `python 3.6`?

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing for running spyder. Recreating the python3 using the following command solves the problem:

```
conda create -n python3 python=3.6 anaconda
```